# Sections don't take the full width of the window in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular5

Here for the smaller screen there is a horizontal scroll , while scrolling I found that the sections don't take the full width of the screen and i dont know why

Can anyone help me please ??
[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwJW4.png)

I tried overflow-x :visible and width:100%  and still the same problem ..
I tried it for components ( navbar and footer ) and for the global style .

[overflow : visible and margin : 0]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvcOQ.png)

Even i tried to give the navbar a constant width

[navbar with constant width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ea0a.png)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)